# XSL rename node using wildcard

Tags: xslt

I have an XML like this:

```
<Temp_Node_A>data</Temp_Node_A>
<Temp_Node_B>data</Temp_Node_B>
```

... etc ...

I want it converted to

```
<Node_A>data</Node_A>
<Node_B>data</Node_B>
```

... etc ...

That is, I want to search for Temp_* and remove Temp_ from every node that match Temp_* (or /Temp_*)

With XSLT 1.0, is it possible? If so, can you give an example?

Regards,
Peter

Comment: you can use the `substring` function, or specifically, the `substring-after` function, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Temp_')]">
    <xsl:element name="{substring-after(name(),'Temp_')}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael!
Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(name(), 'Temp_')">
                <!-- use substring function -->
                <xsl:element name="{substring-after(name(), 'Temp_')}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are applying templates to attributes - but you have no template matching an attribute.

Comment: The identity template was missing, my bad.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time Joel!